# Kubernetes cert-manager issue

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, devops, nginx-ingress

I've deployed cert-manager on cluster. It was working. Recently i noticed that when i try open service which configured through ingress complaining about expired certificate.
I checked in kubernetes certificate shown as its up to date. But when i open service via browser it says that cert expired.

I recreated issuer and certificate again and noticed that cert-manager didnt created "certificaterequest". and "order". So the question is how can i force cert-manager to create cert-request and order.

Comment: Please reserve a time to read the  [**about page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and visit this links to learn  [**how to ask a question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  and  [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  in order to get better and faster answer! Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd would check is what is the actual expire date of the certificate that your browser is receiving while requesting the web page. You can check this by clicking the padlock near the address in your browser.  If this looks correct, check your personal computer time and date whether it's showing the current one (not the future one).

If this is not the case then you can force issuing the certificate with the following methods:

- Set the `renewBefore` field on the `certificate` resource to `1440h (two months before expire date`. It should be enough to trigger the certificate reissuing.
- Delete the `secret` first and then the `certificate`. This will cause the `cert-manager` to issue a new certificate.

Also check out [this](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2641) cert-manager issue on github.